# Emacs "Line-Number mode disabled"

Tags: emacs

I have been trying to simply enable line-number mode in Emacs. I have tried the following:
-M-x linum-mode
   This returns "Not Found"
M-x global-linum-mode
   This returns "Not Found"
M-x line-number mode
   This returns "Line-Number mode disabled"

The last one seems the most descriptive of my problem, but I have not been able to find a solution.

I also added (global-linum-mode t) to my emacs.d/init.el file, if that is relevant. I am very new to Emacs, and any thoughts or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. :)

Comment: TAB doesn't autocomplete "M-x linu" and "C-h f linum-mode" gives me "No match"

Comment: I have version 22.1.1. How would I add linum.el to my installation?

Comment: I found the "load" command for my init file, but where can I get the file? And is it likely that I'm missing other important files? Would it be better to update Emacs rather than just adding that one file?

Comment: Ok, thanks, will do!

Comment: Updated to 24.5.1 and linum-mode works! Thanks! If you add an answer I would be more than happy accept it.

Comment: You possibly now want to install the `nlinum` package (via `M-x package-install`) and use `nlinum-mode` instead. It was written by the previous maintainer of Emacs, and in large buffers it should perform significantly better than `linum`.

Comment: Thanks linum, I did that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since emacs 26.1 you can enable it globally using

```
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
```